# String replacement not working with Dictionary

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a mini dictionary that I would like to use in order to replace occurrences of text within a user's inputted string. However, instead of replacing every occurrence of a particular string, it retains the original string. For example, user types:

"The girl went to school"

My program still returns "The girl went to school". It should come out as "The binguel debbo went to jangirde"

```
func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData

    return (NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()))! as! String
}

var userInput = "" //Declares original user input
var finalSentence:String = "" //Declares a string variable for the final sentence
var newUserString:String

var fulfuldeWords = ["man":"gorko", "woman":"debbo",
    "boy":"binguel gorko", "girl": "binguel debbo", "work":"golle",
    "school":"jangirde", "water":"ndiyam", "horse":"puccu", "cow":"na'i",
    "hat":"hufunere", "house":"wuro", "courage":"cuusal", "camel":"gelodi",
    "milk":"kossam"
]

print("Please enter a sentence to be partially translated: ") //Ask user for input
userInput = input()
var theStringArray = userInput.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

for (englishWord, fulaniWord) in fulfuldeWords {
    finalSentence = userInput.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(englishWord, withString: fulaniWord)
}

print(finalSentence)
```

This is being done in Swift and I don't get why it's not working. Where did I go wrong in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the function `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString` on the same variable to get your desired result. So, in your code, store the result on userInput and print as the output as well.

```
for (englishWord, fulaniWord) in fulfuldeWords {
    userInput = userInput.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(englishWord, withString: fulaniWord)
}

print(userInput)
```